How to solve this partial differential equation for y?
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial \dot{x}} \right) = -b \dot{x}
$$
Here I try to search for $y$ as $y(x,\dot{x},t)$. I tried to find $y$ as $$y(x,\dot{x},t)=f(x)g(\dot{x})z(t)$$ but with no success. I am trying to write a lagrangian for a spring-mass system which also has a damping coefficient $b$ and the added term $y$ aside from the usual $K-V$ needs to satisfy this equation.

Is $x$ supposed to be given or is it free? Could you give some background about why you want to do it this way around? Normally the lagrangian $y$ is given and $x$ is to be found.

Let $$L=e^{bt}\left(\frac{m}{2}\dot x^2-\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2\right)$$
be the lagrangian of the system. Note that
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-e^{bt}m\omega^2x;$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}=be^{bt}m\dot x+e^{bt}m\ddot{x}.$$
Substituting these into the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0,$$
we obtain
$$me^{bt}\left(\ddot x+b\dot x+\omega^2x\right)=0.$$
Since $me^{bt}\neq0$ for all $t$, we arrive at
$$\ddot x+b\dot x+\omega^2x=0$$,
which is the equation that describes a spring-mass system with damping.

You are trying basically to construct the Lagrangian describing a damped harmonic oscillator, which is characterized by a mass $m$, a damping coefficient $b$ and a spring constant $k$. Its equation of motion is given by $m\ddot{x} + b\dot{x} + kx = 0$ and is often reparametrized conventionally as $\ddot{x} + 2\lambda\dot{x} + \omega^2x = 0$, where $\lambda = \frac{b}{2m}$ is simply a renormalized damping coefficient and $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ corresponds the fundamental frequency of the (undamped) harmonic oscillator. Now, several approaches may be followed, here are three of them.
Time-dependent Lagrangian.
It is to be noted that the energy is not conversed in the present system, because the friction term due to $\dot{x}$ induces an energy loss. In consequence, the Lagrangian describing this system won't be necessarily invariant under time-translation, in such a way that one may consider a time-dependent Lagrangian, as already suggested by QuantumSuperfield in his answer. You can verify that $L_{damped} = L_{undamped}e^{2\lambda t} = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2 -\omega^2x^2)e^{2\lambda t}$ will produce the wanted equation of motion.
Ancillary variable.
You may invoke an auxiliary variable $y$ in order to work with a bivariate Lagrangian. You can check that the "mixed" Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}\dot{y} + \lambda(x\dot{y}-\dot{x}y) - \omega^2xy)$ generates the desired equation of motion for $x$.
Let's highlight that the ancillary variable $y$ will obey the same equation of motion with a reversed damping coefficient $\tilde{\lambda} = -\lambda$, meaning that the energy dissipated by $x$ due to damping is reabsorbed by $y$, that is why we might say that the latter models the environment of $x$ itself as a reversed damped harmonic oscillator.
Let's remark in addition that this Lagrangian doesn't depend on time, hence energy conservation on the whole system level, because the energy lost by $x$ is compensated by the energy gained by $y$.
Complex variable.
Another technique makes use of complex variables/parameters. Indeed, given that the damped harmonic oscillator is subjected to an exponential damping, because the solutions of the equation of motion can be parametrized for instance as $x(t) = Ae^{-\lambda t}\cos(\tilde{\omega}t+\phi)$, with $\tilde{\omega} = \sqrt{\omega^2-\lambda^2}$, the exponential prefactor may be reinterpreted as an oscillating factor with complex frequency, so that $x(t)$ can be seen as a superposition of undamped harmonic oscillators with complex frequencies $\tilde{\omega} \pm i\lambda$ respectively.
In consequence, you may use a Lagrange such as $L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{z}^*z-z^*\dot{z}) + im\Omega|z|^2$ for instance (other parametrizations are obviously possible), with $\Omega = \tilde{\omega}+i\lambda$, so that the solutions for $x$ are given by (a linear combination of) the real and imaginary parts of $z$ respectively $-$ or equivalenty by $z$ and its complex conjugate.

Considering a linear spring-mass system as
$$
m\ddot x + b\dot x + k x = 0
$$
the associated lagrangian can be written as
$$
L(x,\dot x) = K - V=\frac m2\dot x^2-\frac k2 x^2
$$
and introducing the dissipation forces
$$
\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = -b\dot x
$$
we have
$$
m\ddot x + k x = -b \dot x 
$$
